# How to store large data for front end use?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on an application in Angular JS 1.5 version.
When i submit a form, based on the input parameters passed, a query is made to the middle layer and data is sent back to the application.

The response received would have around million records. I need to display this data in the form of Graphs on the front-end Using Angular C3 js library.

Can some one please guide me how and where this data received should be stored.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't be stored. Retrieve it from the service, parse it as how you want to display it, destroy when finished using it.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is a client-side MVVM pattern.  The data coming from your middle layer would be loaded into the `viewmodel` which will be databound to the `view`.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't worried about support for older browser, then `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` will probably be your best bet. Most modern browsers will support around 5MB, so you can determine if that's enough. Then in your angular app, you can load the data from the storage into the `viewModel` or a custom angular factory/service in `angular.run()` or the controllers themselves.

But unless you have a very very good reason to actually store 1 million+ records to a browser storage, you should just retrieve it your API when you need it.

On a side note, you will probably want to look the memory usage of your angular app. Especially with a lot of data held in memory, things like `.watch()` and `ng-repeat` can make your application performance suffer.